# Is the topological space $\mathbb{R}$ sequential?

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence

A topological space is called a **sequential space** if a set $A ⊂ X$ is closed if and only if together with any sequence it contains all its limits.

A topological space is called a **Frechet space**, if for $A \subset X$ and $x \in \overline{A}$, there is a sequential of points $A$ s.t converges to $x$.

A topological space is called a **US-space** provided that each convergent sequence has a unique limit.

> (1) **Is the topological space $\mathbb{R}$ sequential? Is there a sequential closed (or open) subset in $\mathbb{R}$?**
>
> (2) **Is the topological space $\mathbb{R}$ Freshet space? or $US$** ?
>
> (3) **Is the product of sequential space, also sequential space?**

Answer (score 2):

$\Bbb R$ is a metric space, so it is automatically Fréchet and hence sequential. Its closed subsets are all sequentially closed, and its open subsets are all sequentially open. It is Hausdorff, so it is automatically $US$. [This post](http://dantopology.wordpress.com/2010/07/21/sequential-spaces-v/) to Dan Ma’s Topology Blog contains an example of a non-sequential product of two sequential spaces. (In fact one of the factors is even first countable, and the other is Fréchet, so they are sequential in a very strong way.)

Comment: Is $[0,\omega_1)$ a non closed countably compact in $\mathbb{R}$?If the answer is yes, so $\mathbb{R}$ is not strongly $T_B$ space. Since strongly $T_B$ space is $T_B$, it follow that $\mathbb{R}$ is not $T_B$, but it is in contradiction with $T_B$ space $\mathbb{R}$. Is it right?

Comment: @Ebi: $[0,\omega_1)$ cannot be embedded in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: could you give more explain?Thanks.

Comment: @Ebi: One way to see it is to observe that $[0,\omega_1)$ is not Lindelöf: $\{[0,\alpha):\alpha<\omega_1\}$ is an open cover of $[0,\omega_1)$ with no countable subcover. $\Bbb R$, on the other hand, is second countable, so it’s hereditarily Lindelöf: every subspace of $\Bbb R$ is Lindelöf. Thus, $\Bbb R$ cannot have a subspace homeomorphic to $[0,\omega_1)$.

Comment: In cofinite  topology space (X,$\tau$),$X$ is compact and $T_1$, but is not $US$ space.But  it is not true for $\mathbb{R}$, **why**? or even in cocountably topology on $\mathbb{R}$, space $\mathbb{R}$ is $US$ and non- Hausdorff.(I mean, generally $\mathbb{R}$ is not $US$ or Hausdorff. Is it right?)

Comment: @Ebi: I don’t really understand the question. When we talk about $\Bbb R$ as a topological space, we mean $\Bbb R$ with its usual metric topology unless we specifically give it some other topology. With its usual topology $\Bbb R$ is Hausdorff and therefore $US$. If you just treat $\Bbb R$ as a set, you can put all sorts of topologies on it; some will be Hausdorff and therefore $US$, some will be $US$ but not Hausdorff, and some will not even be $US$. Until you specify the topology, nothing can be said about it.